# getting properly words form array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, format

I'm having a problem with proper printing from an array.

In IF(A), 
That should format all input letters in that way.

c a t d o g etc etc

But, the following only formats the last word I write. I'm only guessing why, and don't know how to fix it.

That part is marked with :**"

```
String type;
String word;
String words[]=new String[100];
int i=0;

String k="end";
System.out.println("Type word: ");
word=sc.next();

while(wyraz.compareToIgnoreCase(k)!=0){     
    words[i]=wyraz;
    i=i+1;
    word=sc.next();
}   
words[i]=k;

System.out.println("Choose type A,B,C:");
type=sc.next();



**if(type.equals("A")){
    int length=word.length();

    for(int z=0;z<length;z++){
    System.out.print(words[z]=""+word.charAt(z));
    System.out.print(" ");
}**


if(type.equals("B")){
    int length=i+1;

    for(int x=0;x<length;x++){
        System.out.print(words[x]);
        System.out.println();   
    }
}

if(type.equals("C")){

    int length=i+1;
    int j;

    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
            System.out.print(words[j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are not iterating through all indexes

```
if(type.equals("A")){
  //iterate through all words except for "end"
  for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
    //iterate through specific word's characters 
    for(int z=0;z<words[x].length();z++){
      //actually print
      System.out.print(words[x].charAt(z)+ " ");
    }
  }
}
```

This should, if you have e words (eg `"cat"`, `"dog"`, `"end"`), output as `"c a t d o g"`. If you want to also have the "e n d", change

```
for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
```

to

```
for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++){
```

I will also say that since you're using an array the user can end prematurely (leaving the rest of the indexes `null`, you should consider using an`ArrayList <String>` instead.

Comment: Thanks! a lot :) Now i understand, where was the problem.